# How I can rid of the space of my svg with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to put this picture (SVG) in my html doc and trying to put some style, but it have some spaces that I don't want, like you can see with the red borders, is there any chances to get rid of that with css (if there's any posibility of that)?

[image]

Everything is inside a `<div>`, the **SVG** have a `<div>` too, and the text under is a `<h2>`.

Like this:

```
<div class="info-logo">
    <div class="logo-car">
        <img src="name_file.svg" alt="Lil car">
    </div>
    <h2>This is a place where you can find your next car.</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe look into cropping an image using CSS

Answer (score 1):

Probably your SVG has a viewBox attribute, if I'm right, you can adjusts the size and position of the svg content.

[viewBox - Mozilla Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox)

[SVG Attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute)

Open your svg on the browser, and adjusts using DevTolls (F12).

Answer (score 0):

svg is an inline element. You will need to add `display:block` to the svg and then apply css block display styles.